# Cannot upload files with ACL public-read to Digital Ocean spaces

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm trying to upload images to a Digital Ocean space from the browser. These images should be public. I'm able to upload the images successfully.

**However, though the ACL is set to `public-read`, the uploaded files are always private**.

I know they're private because a) the dashboard says that the permissions are "private", and b) because the public urls don't work, and c) manually changing the permissions to "public" in the dashboard fixes everything.

Here's the overall process I'm using.

1. Create a pre-signed URL on the backend
2. Send that url to the browser
3. Upload the image to that pre-signed url

Any ideas why the images aren't public?

### Code

The following examples are written in TypeScript and use AWS's v3 SDK.

#### Backend

This generates the pre-signed url to upload a file.

```js
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner'

const client = new S3Client({
    region: 'nyc3',
    endpoint: 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.DIGITAL_OCEAN_SPACES_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.DIGITAL_OCEAN_SPACES_SECRET,
    },
})

const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key: fileName,
    ContentType: mime,
})

const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command)
```

The pre-signed url is then sent to the browser.

#### Frontend

This is the code on the client to actually upload the file to Digital Ocean. `file` is a [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

```
const uploadResponse = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
        'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=31536000,immutable',
    },
    body: file,
    method: 'PUT',
})
```

### Metadata

- AWS SDK: 3.8.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that for Digital Ocean, you also need to set the `public-read` ACL as a header in the put request.

```
//front-end
const uploadResponse = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
        'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=31536000,immutable',
        'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', // add this line
    },
    body: file,
    method: 'PUT',
})
```

Comment: Life saver. I have not seen this in any of the Digital Ocean docs. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, was struggling with that for a bit.

Comment: And don't forget to add the `x-amz-acl` header to the allowed origins :)
Settings > CORS Configurations >  Add or Edit > Allowed Headers

Comment: I have been using the presigned_post_url and tried it but its not working in that, can anyone help me in understanding how to do so?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent so much time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment, hence adding a response. Thank you @Nick ... this is one of the few working examples of code I have seen for DigitalOcean pre-signed url. While the [official DigitalOcean description here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/resources/s3-sdk-examples/) mentions `Content-Type` is needed for uploading with pre-signed urls, there is **no example code**.

Another mistake that prevented me from uploading a file using pre-signed URLs in DigitalOcean was using `'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'` and `FormData()`.

After seeing this post, I followed @Nick's suggestion of using a `File()` object and `'Content-Type':'<relevant_mime>'`. Then, the file upload worked like a charm. This is also not covered in official docs.

Answer (score 1):

don't have enough reputation to comment but thanks so much for the help  @nick.
That worked like a charm. I added

```
 ContentType: ' Headers: {
    'Content-Type': file.type,
    'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=31536000,immutable',
    'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', // add this line
  },
  ContentType: '<relevant_mime>',',
```

and it worked perfectly <3

Answer (score 0):

Try this to force ACL to Public in Digital Ocean Spaces:

```
s3cmd --access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY --secret_key=YOUR_SECRET_KEY --host=YOUR_BUCKET_REGION.digitaloceanspaces.com --host-bucket=YOUR_BUCKET_NAME.YOUR_BUCKET_REGION.digitaloceanspaces.com --region=YOUR_BUCKET_REGION setacl s3://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME --acl-public
```